# Decode custom JSON claim from JwtSecurityTokenHandler

Tags: c#, jwt

I have a JWT which I want to decode using the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler` class from the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` package. I can decode all standard claims without problem.

However I have a custom claim in the JWT which looks as follows:

```
{
  "exp": 1632825287,
  ...
  "my_custom_claim": {
    "ctx": "...",
    "act": "a826e63f-1c31-4f01-b432-f1264794e7ac"
  }
}
```

I use the following code:

```
var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var decodedJwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(encodedJwtToken);
object customClaim = decodedJwtToken.Payload["my_custom_claim"];
// customClaim is wrapped as object, the underlying type is Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.Linq.JObject
```

My question is: How can I decode/access the value of the "act" subclaim which is contained in "my_custom_claim"?
Because all types within the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json` namespace are internal, I have no chance to decode it.

Comment: `var act = decodedJwtToken.Payload["my_custom_claim"]["act"]`?

Comment: That doesn't work because `decodedJwtToken.Payload["my_custom_claim"]` is of type object. It throws "error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'".

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the claims from the JWT as `Dictionary<string, string>` and then by using `Newtonsoft.Json` (or any other equivalent to it) deserialize the custom claim JSON to a specific type.

```cs
class CustomClaimType 
{
    public string Ctx { get; set; }
    public string Act{ get; set; }
    // other props ... 
}

var encodedToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJK....";
var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var decodedToken = jwtTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(encodedToken);

var claims = decodedToken.Claims
    .GroupBy(claim => claim.Type) // handle arrays
    .ToDictionary(
         claim => claim.Key, 
         claim => string.Join(" ", claim.Select(claim => claim.Value)));

var customClaim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomClaimType>(
    claims["my_custom_claim"], 
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
    });
```

Comment: In the meantime I have come up with a similar solution, also utilizing `Newtonsoft.Json`. I wanted to avoid that, but there seems to be no other possibility.
I will post my answer for completeness.
Thanks anyhow for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to use in addition the `Newtonsoft.Json` package, which I originally wanted to avoid.
The simplest solution I came up with is:

```
var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var decodedJwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(encodedJwtToken);
var customClaim = decodedJwtToken.Claims.Single(claim => claim.Type == "my_custom_claim");
// The following line requires: using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
var actClaim = JObject.Parse(customClaim.Value)["act"].ToString();
```